# android - animate searchview icon in toolbar from side to side

Tags: android, animation, toolbar, searchview

When click the **Search** *icon* in **Toolbar**, it immediately appears on the other side (the same for cancelling the search). Is it possible to *animate* its move? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: this is the same answer as [Android: animate searchview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600528/android-animate-searchview).

There is an easier approach (in fact, just two more lines of code) and it's bug-free. What you have to do is populating your SearchView in the onCreateOptionsMenu() method like you would have done before, but avoiding the lines of code where you set the transition, as they are not needed anymore.

Next, override onOptionsItemSelected() like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
            MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(item);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This code prepares a transition and listens for changes in the toolbar layout. When the SearchView appears, the animation starts. It uses the same API as KitKat but it is available starting with ICS. In your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:transition:24.2.1'
```

You can also [customize the transition](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/transitions.html) if you don't like the default one. There are many transitions available and some that fit your needs for sure

Answer (score 2):

I've created a library just for that.
If this is what you are looking for:
[image]

Check my library at https://github.com/UdiOshi85/libSearchToolbar