# Android: animate searchview

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm trying to implement an animated searchview (with a simple extend/collapse animation) but all the answers in this forum are not working.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48px"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

what i've done

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    //Get the ID for the search bar LinearLayout
    int searchBarId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_bar", null, null);
    //Get the search bar Linearlayout
    LinearLayout searchBar = (LinearLayout) 
            searchView.findViewById(searchBarId);
    //Give the Linearlayout a transition animation.
    searchBar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
    return true;
}
```

all the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.daveslab.wideview, PID: 2459
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setLayoutTransition(android.animation.LayoutTransition)' on a null object reference
                  at com.daveslab.wideview.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:69)
                  at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2846)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:360)
                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:88)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:331)
                  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:88)
                  at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:454)
                  at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

errors in values.xml(all the icons are in the project with the correct name):

```
Error:(1605, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchBackIcon'.
```

Error:(1602, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchBackground'.
Error:(1604, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchCloseIcon'.
Error:(1606, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchSuggestionBackground'.
Error:(1603, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchVoiceIcon'.
Error:(1605, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchBackIcon'.
Error:(1602, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchBackground'.
Error:(1604, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchCloseIcon'.
Error:(1606, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchSuggestionBackground'.
Error:(1603, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchVoiceIcon'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easier approach (in fact, just two more lines of code) and it's bug-free. What you have to do is populating your SearchView in the onCreateOptionsMenu() method like you would have done before, but avoiding the lines of code where you set the transition, as they are not needed anymore.

Next, override onOptionsItemSelected() like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
            MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(item);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This code prepares a transition and listens for changes in the toolbar layout. When the SearchView appears, the animation starts. It uses the same API as KitKat but it is available starting with ICS. In your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:transition:24.2.1'
```

You can also [customize the transition](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/transitions.html) if you don't like the default one.

Comment: That's because that code is run from a fragment. If you're handling SearchView from an activity, simply use findViewById(...)

Comment: I'm running it by MainActivity.java

Comment: In that case, your code line is TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

Comment: ok now it works, but it kingìd of disappears for some seconds. is possible to achieve a visible transiction?

Comment: You can always customize the transition, providing your own set. The animation you see is the default one (the one that the system selects). There is a method TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(ViewGroup, Transition), where you provide your custom animation. More about that in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html and https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

I am bit late to answer but above answers not worked for me.

```
     SearchView searchView;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.application_menu, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        LinearLayout searchBar = (LinearLayout) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        searchBar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
 return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

And my **application_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
         />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you.But accept the answer if it solves your problem.So,It will help others too.

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
//Get the ID for the search bar LinearLayout
int searchBarId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_bar", null, null);
//Get the search bar Linearlayout
 LinearLayout searchBar = (LinearLayout)       
 searchView.findViewById(searchBarId);
 //Give the Linearlayout a transition animation.
 searchBar.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());
```

Styles.xml

```
  <style name="MaterialSearchViewStyle">
    <item name="searchBackground">@color/white_ish</item>
    <item name="searchVoiceIcon">@drawable/ic_action_voice_search</item>
    <item name="searchCloseIcon">@drawable/ic_action_navigation_close</item>
    <item name="searchBackIcon">@drawable/ic_action_navigation_arrow_back</item>
    <item name="searchSuggestionBackground">@color/search_layover_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/gray_50</item>
    <item name="android:hint">@string/search_hint</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">textCapWords</item>
</style>
```

Use that style in your xml

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:title="@string/action_search"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48px"
app:showAsAction="always"
 style="@style/MaterialSearchViewStyle"/>
```

Comment: And the console log

Comment: @DavideNale after putiing this code? and please share error imnage

Comment: Ok. Look up in the question body.

Comment: @DavideNale you have to define style

Comment: @DavideNale added in answer